# How do I cite previously published print school newspapers on now online school newspaper?

Tags: citations, journalism

I'm the adviser of a school newspaper that publishes exclusively online now. We have a page dedicated to revisiting the archives of our paper (60 years worth!). I cannot piece together how to properly cite in an article what has been quoted or paraphrased from the previously published article.

Do I cite the author and year? Article title in the credit? What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Hi TheChant, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. This is a good first question. I made a minor edit to suit the style of the site better, if you have any issues you can [edit] further or rollback my changes. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 3):

Print publications that are no longer in print are (were) still print publications.  You would therefore cite them the same way you would any other newspaper article from a still-extant paper.  (Citation format varies by style guide.)  However, if you only accessed it via an intermediary, like a compilation (bound volume) or a digital archive, then you should *also* cite where *you* found it.  One way to do that (again, your style guide might have opinions on this) would be:

> Rosenberg, G. (1997, March 31). Electronic discovery proves an effective legal weapon. The New York Times, p. D5, as reproduced in __, The New York Times Compilation, Volume 103, p. 1952.

(This is an adaptation of [APA style](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/apa/newspaper/).)

You said "quoted or paraphrased".  A *paraphrase* is a different work, so follow your style guide's rules for how to cite Source A adapting Source B.  In my experience you would *cite* Source A there, because that's the source you used, and you might say *in the body of your work* (not as a citation) that this is a paraphrase of Source B.

A general rule for citations is: cite what you used, and never cite something you didn't see.  In my last example, you never saw the original (Source B), so you cannot cite it.  What if Source A was wrong in its claims about Source B?